# Displaying images when rendering rich text in a desktop application

Tags: basecamp

I'm writing a desktop application which should render (among other things) Basecamp 3 rich texts. A rich text is a simple HTML and my application display HTML documents through an embedded web component.

This is working great except for displaying images. The HTML returned by Basecamp 3 API may reference pictures hosted at https://preview.3.basecamp.com. Unfortunately, these pictures are only accessible when the user is actually logged in on the web component: being authenticated through OAUTH as is required by Basecamp API won't give you access to the pictures.

As you can see on the screenshot below, the web component can render the HTML but fails to download the picture and shows a big grey box instead.

[image]

A workaround is to ask my users to copy/paste cookies from their web browser to the desktop application. This is not an easy task for everyone.

How do I grant my web component access to the pictures hosted outside the Basecamp 3 API?